# How linkedin and other social media plaformation are dipslying content to public url

Tags: image, url

when every copy past my linkedin or other social media url. it is displaying name, description image. How to implement such kind of functionality. i did research but no idea.

I dont have clue. i did search on it but no lead.

Reference Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The system scans the link against known platforms database then pulls the rest of the data from the mentioned platform using an open API.

Comment: <meta property="og:site_name" content="$site_name" />
<meta property="og:url" content="$site_url" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="$the_title" />
<meta name="image" property="og:image" content="$site_logo"/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1024">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1024">
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="$site_description" />

Comment: <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" description="@username" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="$the_title" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="$site_description" />
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="$site_logo">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="$site_url">

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried above code but it is only for single. it is not working for multiple user profile similar to linked, twitter